# How do you install Django when there is a problem with scl?

Tags: rhel, python, scl

scl is installed on RedHat 6.  The man pages for scl work.  I want to install Django.  I believe that a prerequisite is to install SCL for Python.

```
$scl -l
```

returns nothing.  I believe that this is a problem.  But I don't know what I did wrong.

```
python --version
```

returns Python 2.7.5

I ran this command:

```
scl enable python27 bash
```

It returned this:

```
Unable to open /etc/scl/conf/python27!
```

I tried `scl enable python275 bash` too.  How do I get to enable Python 2.7 with scl?  I believe I'll have problems with installing Django based on the directions that I read.  There are no files in /etc/scl/conf/.  What should I do to get Django installed?

Update (6/24/16):
When I tried to run this `sudo yum install python27`

I received this:

> Error: Package: python27-python-libs-2.7.5-10.el6.x86_64
>   (scl_python27)
>              Requires: libffi.so.5()(64bit) Error: Package: python27-python-libs-2.7.5-10.el6.x86_64 (scl_python27)
>              Requires: libgdbm.so.2()(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

I tried to install the relevant RPMs.  I got a message that a newer version was already installed.  I'd rather not downgrade Python from 2.7.5 to 2.7.3.

I tried skip-broken (with `sudo yum install python27`), but I received this:

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:

> compat-db-headers-4.7.25-28.el7.noarch from
>   rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
>       compat-db47-4.7.25-28.el7.x86_64 from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
>       python27-1.1-15.el6.x86_64 from scl_python27
>       python27-python-2.7.5-10.el6.x86_64 from scl_python27
>       python27-python-babel-0.9.6-7.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-python-devel-2.7.5-10.el6.x86_64 from scl_python27
>       python27-python-docutils-0.11-1.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-python-jinja2-2.6-9.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-python-libs-2.7.5-10.el6.x86_64 from scl_python27
>       python27-python-markupsafe-0.11-11.el6.x86_64 from scl_python27
>       python27-python-nose-1.3.0-1.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-python-pygments-1.5-2.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-python-setuptools-0.9.8-1.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-python-simplejson-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64 from scl_python27
>       python27-python-sphinx-1.1.3-7.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-python-sqlalchemy-0.7.9-3.el6.x86_64 from scl_python27
>       python27-python-virtualenv-1.10.1-2.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-python-werkzeug-0.8.3-5.el6.noarch from scl_python27
>       python27-runtime-1.1-15.el6.x86_64 from scl_python27

This command still returns nothing (no errors, just goes to the next prompt):

```
scl -l
```

Comment: Did you edit `scl.repo` as shown [here](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2013/02/14/setting-up-django-and-python-2-7-on-red-hat-enterprise-6-the-easy-way/)?

Comment: I tried.  I ran this: "sudo yum install python27" and I received this:
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Config error: File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/scl.repo, line: 1
'c/p from http://people.redhat.com/bkabrda/scl_python27.repo\n'

Comment: Or...you can use python virtualenv to create a separate installation of python in user's home directory.  Then, you can do `pip install django`